# Como posso escrever o comando de entrada de dados externos em Java?

Tags: java, c

Migrei do C para Java e gostaria de saber qual o comando que permite ao usuário inserir dados externos e como seria esse comando em código.

Na linguagem em `C` uso o código abaixo:

```
scanf(%tipo_da_variavel, &nome_da_variavel);
```

Comment: Qual comando você usa no C?

Comment: No C seria o scanf(%tipo_da_variavel, &nome_da_variavel);

Comment: No java é `Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in); int n = ler.nextInt();`

Comment: @acklay quer responder?

Comment: @acklay reabri.

Answer (score 1):

O `scanf()` no C, é equivalente ao [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) no Java. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// valores do tipo inteiros
int n = scanner.nextInt();

// valores do tipo strings
String s = scanner.nextLine(); 

// valores do tipo double
double d = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Veja mais detalhes e exemplos na documentação sobre a [classe Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner).